# How can I make different windows appear on specified workspaces on startup?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, 17.10, startup-applications

(Running 17.10 with Gnome)

So, I like having a few windows in set positions and workspaces at all times. But it's tedious to move them all manually every time. I've got some in the Startup Applications and using the Gnome extension "Auto Move Windows" to kinda put them where they go, but it's not really accomplishing the "hands off" result I want.

For instance:
I use 9 workspaces (set with Gnome extension "Workspace Grid"), and I want Keep and Hangouts on Workspace 1, splitting the desktop side-by-side; a Chrome window with my personal account on Workspace 2 maximized; and another Chrome window with my work account on Workspace 3.

Now, the problem arises with using Auto Move Windows because it operates per application - that is, it looks for every launch of an application and moves it to the given workspace. But 3 of the 4 things I want are "Chrome" (keep seems to behave like its own app, and appears in the app list of Auto Move Windows), and so on startup, they all stack up on Workspace 2 and I have to move them manually.

It seems small, but I feel like there should be a way to instruct the Startup Applications module to open each given object on a given workspace. Something like "/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U workspace(3)".

Coupled with this is the multiple user problem - how can I specify to startup applications that one instance of Chrome be opened with one account and the other instance with the other account?

Any ideas?